# Javascript inserted elements appear/update in Firefox & Chrome, but not Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Really appreciate if you could help me shed some light on this.

I'm constructing a drag and drop object oriented JavaScript interface, however I am unable to get even basic modifications to update on the screen in IE8.  It works perfectly in FF and Chrome.  Check out:

http://gfe.ca/JAShowcaseBuilder/test2.html

You will probably notice that this is a true object-oriented design, meaning that multiple files work in tandem, so I can't just post a snippet of code here.  I *think* Line 164 of file JAShowcaseBuilderDraggableComponentClass.js is a good starting point.  I *can* verify that the code executes and doesn't terminate prematurely.  What modifications must I make for IE8 compatibility?  IE8 *doesn't* generate any errors at all, even when "`Tools -> Internet Options -> Advanced -> Browsing -> Display a notification about every script error`" is ticked.  The damn IE8 debugger doesn't even display dynamic changes to the DOM when the script runs (like Chrome and Firefox).

UPDATE:
Unfortunately I've determined that I can't live without element translucency.  I've determined that static page elements can be made translucent by setting BOTH of the following style properties:

```
-ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=50)
filter: alpha(opacity=50)
```

This has been done successfully on a new small green div that has been defined within the HTML.  Unfortunately the following code *doesn't* do the same when set within javascript:

```
this.dragHelperDivElementReference.css("filter", "alpha(opacity="+String(this.dragHelperDivOpacityNumber)+")");

this.dragHelperDivElementReference.css("-ms-filter", "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity="+String(this.dragHelperDivOpacityNumber)+")");
```

For starters, in the case of the green box (which works) the DOM model presented in IE8's debugger doesn't show the "`-ms-filter`" property at all.  The DOM model for the red box (which doesn't work) shows the property incorrectly as "`msfilter`" (no dashes).  Any ideas?

UPDATE #2:
Figured it out.  The transparency *cannot* be applied to the parent Div element, which on its own has no width or height.  It must be instead applied to the child element.  Needless to say, I loathe IE8 and Microsoft in general.  A special thanks to scessor (http://stackoverflow.com/users/843985/scessor) for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: If you want more people to help, you should include the relevant code right in your post.  Having a link to a working page is good, but asking people to wade through ten JS files in your web page to try to find the relevant code is not going to yield many helpers.

Comment: Just FYI, the IE 8 debugger isn't quite as bad as you're saying. You just have to hit the little "refresh" icon in the HTML tab in the debugger to see the DOM as of that moment. Still, real-time would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this just after < html >

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to do anything useful.  Is it meant to provide IE7 compatibility?  I can't even get this thing to work in IE8!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `css opacity filter`. The IE8 needs
`-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";`
instead of `filter: alpha(opacity=50);`.

=== UPDATE ===

Maybe following code works in all IE: In the file `JAShowcaseBuilderClass.js` replace lines 101 - 110 with:

```
var sVersion = $.browser.version.substr(0, 2);
if (sVersion == '5.' || sVersion == '6.' || sVersion == '7.') {
    this.dragHelperDivElementReference.css(
        "filter",
        "alpha(opacity=" + String(this.dragHelperDivOpacityNumber) + ")"
    );
} else if (sVersion == '8.') {
    this.dragHelperDivElementReference.css(
        "filter",
        "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=" + String(this.dragHelperDivOpacityNumber) + ")"
    );
} else {
    this.dragHelperDivElementReference.css(
        "opacity", 
        String(this.dragHelperDivOpacityNumber / 100)
    );
}
```

Also see my [IE test](http://jsfiddle.net/L7r3Z/).

Comment: This is good in that it points out exactly where the problem is.  That's 90% of the solution.  Unfortunately I've been unable to come up with a permutation of the code segment you've supplied which yields a translucent element.  Google searches have shown that what you're suggesting *should* work however.  At least now I can simply remove the filter entirely and have drag and drop functionality, if only without translucency.  Thanks!